# Concatenating parameters in struts2 iframe load

Tags: java, jsp, iframe, struts2, ognl

using Struts2, I successfully load an external URL inside a jsp page using an iframe like this:

```
<iframe src="http://www.abcd.com/somedir/index.php">
</iframe>
```

I’m also able to pass a request parameter in the URL like this:

```
<iframe src="http://www.abcd.com/somedir/index.php?sid=999">
</iframe>
```

The problem comes when I try to concatenate that parameter, loading it from the Strus2 stack:

```
<iframe src="http://www.abcd.com/somedir/index.php?sid=<s:property value="sid" />">
</iframe>
```

Could some body help me to achieve that?

Thanks

Comment: what happens when you do that ?

Comment: parameter will be loaded correctly with your syntax.so what is the problem you are getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jigar and Umesh, sorry for the delay..

I finally use something like this:

```
<iframe src="http://www.abcd.com/somedir/index.php?sid=<s:property value="#parameters.sid" />">
</iframe>
```

...and the invocation through:

```
http://www.xyz.com/somenamespace/someaction?sid=123456
```

Comment: This post should be posted as an update to your question, not as an answer. Please read more in [the FAQ section](http://stackoverflow.com/faq).